# Woocommerce Bookings - Resource needs to be allocated for part of the booking duration, not the whole booking

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

Using Woocommerce Bookings plugin, I need to create some bookable products that have resources attached to them, but only for part of the booking duration.

e.g. The bookable event is a party that lasts 2 hours. It needs to have resource 1 allocated to it for the first hour, then resource 2 allocated for the second hour.

How can I acheive this?

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your requirement of allocating 2 resources at the same time for one booking is currently not possible using the WooCommerce Bookings plugin.

However, WooCommerce bookings by PluginHive provides a lot of customisation packages using which you might be able to achieve your business requirement.

You can check out their customisation packages from here:  https://www.pluginhive.com/product/customization-for-pluginhive-woocommerce-plugins/

Alternatively, you can also reach out to PluginHive booking experts team from here: https://www.pluginhive.com/support/ and they will definitely help you out in how to achieve your business requirement.